# Wrap list items to create embedded lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using javascript and jQuery, I've turned a table rendered in the browser into a list. So I have...

```
<ul id="side-navigation">
    <li></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li3"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li3"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li2"></li>
    <li class="li3"></li>
    <li class="li3"></li>
    <li class="li3"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

But I want to create embedded list based upon their classes. Like this...

```
<ul id="side-navigation">
    <li>
        <ul>    
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2">
                <ul>
                    <li class="li3"></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2">
                <ul>
                    <li class="li3"></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
             <li class="li2"></li>
             <li class="li2"></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
    <li>
        <ul>    
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2"></li>
            <li class="li2">
                <ul>
                    <li class="li3"></li>
                    <li class="li3"></li>
                    <li class="li3"></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Before this web designer, not programmer, tries to figure out how, I figured some smart person might have a suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a jquery script to parse your current tab and add before / after your tags

```
$( ".li3" ).before( "<ul>" );
$( ".li3" ).after( "</ul>" );
```

This may not be the niciest solution but should workd

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, it's good practice to place any html inside an `ol` or `ul` inside a `li` element. For example.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Hello
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>World</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As such, I believe you should do it as follows:

```
$( ".li3" ).append('<ul><li class="yourClass">Your content here</li></ul>');
```